# List won't display it's content

Tags: c#, list, button, windows-phone-8

I want to make an app that shows the shops that are currently open. Each shop has a name, work hours and a category. I made a list which contains each shop and its attributes, but when i use the foreach method it wont display any of them... Do you happen to know what the problem is ? or a different way to solve it?

```
 class Shop
 {
    public string name;
    public DayOfWeek day{ get; set; }
    public TimeSpan start{ get; set; }
    public TimeSpan end{ get; set; }
    public string address{ get; set; }
    public string category{ get; set; }




    public Shop(string name, DayOfWeek day, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, string address, string category)
        {
        name = this.name;
        day = this.day;
        start = this.start;
        end = this.end;
        address = this.address;
        category = this.category;
        }
    }


    public openshops()
    {
        List<Shop> openShop = new List<Shop>();
        openShop.Add(new Shop("ill forno", DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0), "ermoupoli", "pizza"));
        openShop.Add(new Shop("Η ΣΥΡΑ", DayOfWeek.Sunday, new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0), "ermoupoli", "pizza"));
        openShop.Add(new Shop("ΠΙΤΑΚΙ", DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeSpan(19, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(00, 30, 0), "ermoupoli", "souvlaki"));

        this.InitializeComponent();


        DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if (today == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            foreach (Shop shop in openShop)
            {
                if ((now > shop.start) && (now < shop.end))
                {
                    Button btn = new Button();
                    btn.Content = shop.name;
                    myStackPanel.Children.Add(btn);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is openshops() being called?  If so, can you show the code that calls it?

Comment: Also, I'm curious why there is a call to `InitializeComponent()` if this class doesn't inherit from a Form or something.

Comment: openshops is the name of the new page i created, and this code inside openshops.xaml.cs  exists by default: public openshops() { this.InitializeComponent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to fixing how you set your properties you also have an issue with the start and end times.

```
openShop.Add(new Shop("ill forno", DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0), "ermoupoli", "pizza"));
openShop.Add(new Shop("Η ΣΥΡΑ", DayOfWeek.Sunday, new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0), "ermoupoli", "pizza"));
openShop.Add(new Shop("ΠΙΤΑΚΙ", DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeSpan(19, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(00, 30, 0), "ermoupoli", "souvlaki"));
```

These `Shop` objects will have start times that are greater than the end times, so this `if` statement

```
if ((now > shop.start) && (now < shop.end))
```

Will always be false for these `Shop` objects.  I'm guessing that you actually want to swap those values.

```
openShop.Add(new Shop("ill forno", DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0), "ermoupoli", "pizza"));
openShop.Add(new Shop("Η ΣΥΡΑ", DayOfWeek.Sunday, new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0), "ermoupoli", "pizza"));
openShop.Add(new Shop("ΠΙΤΑΚΙ", DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeSpan(00, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(19, 30, 0), "ermoupoli", "souvlaki"));
```

Comment: oh i see instead of (00,0,0) i should have written (24,0,0) .. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: @KatDale Yes, (24,0,0) would be a good exclusive upper bound for time of day.  (0,0,0) would then be an inclusive lower bound.  Assuming you make those values the acceptable range for `start` and `end` then your `if` should probably be `if(now >= shop.start && now < shop.end)`

Answer (score 8):

You are reversing the setting logic in your constructor:

You should set members like this:

```
public Shop(string name, DayOfWeek day, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, string address, string category)
    {
    this.name = name;
    this.day = day;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.address = address;
    this.category = category;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Shop(string name, DayOfWeek day, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, string address, string category)
    {
    name = this.name;
    day = this.day;
    start = this.start;
    end = this.end;
    address = this.address;
    category = this.category;
    }
}
```

You are setting the parameters values to uninstantiated variables from your class...

the keyword

> this

Is used to refer to the current object instance.

Also, by convention, property names should be Pascal case, so if you reformat your code to:

```
class Shop
{
//public string name; //This one should have getters and setters too, fields shouldn't be exposed.
public string Name { get; set; }
public DayOfWeek Day{ get; set; }
public TimeSpan Start{ get; set; }
public TimeSpan End{ get; set; }
public string Address{ get; set; }
public string Category{ get; set; }




public Shop(string name, DayOfWeek day, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, string address, string category)
    {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Day = day;
    this.Start = start;
    this.End = end;
    this.Address = address;
    this.Category = category;
    }
}
```

Everything should be ok.

Reference about convention:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Reference about exposing class fields:
http://thatextramile.be/blog/2009/10/slutty-types/